# Do buying "Appearance" things in AC4 do anything to the Jackdaw other than appearance?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Other than the item you buy, will it change anything else like, health, Attack etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they only make your ship look awesome